# google analytics - real-time user stats vs audience overview user stats

Tags: google-analytics

When looking at the real-time analytics reporting for our app, it shows around 150-180 users, say around 10AM (our peak usage time). When I look at the Audience Overview report for the same day (hourly breakdown), the number of users shown for the 10AM hour is over 1000. I'm sure this has to do with some sort of aggregation, but I would like to know more about how these two numbers are calculated in order to understand it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's an aggregate When you look at analytics in non real time reporting, you are actually seeing the traffic of the whole hour (60 minutes). When you look at 10AM on your real-time report, you see who's online that same moment.